# Ampscript condition else/if, how do we show a multiple list condition with 2 same values but different last word?

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, dataextensions

I have DE lists like this for "Fruits" category:

"Apple", "Apple Ba", "Apple 2", "Apple red", "Apple green", "Apple CA", "Mango", "Mango Lala", "Mango B", "Mango White", "Mango special", "Mango yes" etc

Basically I need to show all those list within the fruit category for Apple and Mango
My condition for the fruits:

```
SET @Fruits= AttributeValue("Fruits")

%%[ IF @Fruits== "Apple" OR @Fruits== "Apple CA" THEN OR @Fruits== "Apple 2" THEN]%%

This apple is the best apple in the world

%%[ ELSEIF @Fruits== "Mango" OR @Fruits== "Mango Lala" OR @Fruits== "Mango B" THEN ]%%

This mango is the best mango in the world

ELSE ]%%
                       
%%[ ENDIF ]%%
```

Is there a simple way so I don't need to create those multiple conditions with OR?
Like I just show Apple and it will show all the Apple list within that Apple keyword, same goes if I just want to show only Mango list.

Comment: I'm guessing using a substring and indexof ampscript may help here

Comment: Can you give sample how to pull this off? I tried but doesn’t seem to work or maybe I’m missing something

Comment: I would suggest adding what you tried for the above functions

Comment: The condition else if is the one I come up with, but no clue how to use substring or indexof

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
%%[
    set @fruits = AttributeValue("Fruits")
    if IndexOf(@fruits, 'apple') > 0 then
]%%

We have an apple here!

%%[
    elseif IndexOf(@fruits, 'mango') > 0 then
]%%

Nah, it's just a mango.

%%[else]%%

We don't have any apples or mangos here.

%%[endif]%%
```

Learn how to use IndexOf function: [reference](https://ampscript.guide/indexof/)

Comment: This is working, thanks a lot!